# PHP UPDATE not inserting in database clean row

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a small system, which should update certain things. It includes a form.

```
if(isset($_GET['bevestiging'])) {
$kamerurl= $_POST['kamer'];
mysql_query("UPDATE volg_dj_aan_uit SET (aan_of_uit,kamerurl) VALUES ('aanzetten','$kamerurl')");
echo '<b>Geupdate!!</b>
<br>
Het volgen is aangezet!
<br>
<a href="index.php?p=tools_volg_kamer" target="_self">Verder »</a>';
}
```

It check if "bevestiging" is set (which is) then the posted URL from $_POST['kamer'] should be transferred to $kamerurl but it's an empty result. And it also sets the "aanzetten" to 0 instead of "aanzetten" here is the form in PHP:

```
else {
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM volg_dj_aan_uit");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
if($row['aan_of_uit'] == "uitzetten") {
$aanofuit = "aanzetten";
} else if($row['aan_of_uit'] == "aanzetten") {
$aanofuit = "uitzetten";
}
echo 'Vul de kamerurl in: <form method="post" action="index.php?p=tools_volg_kamer&bevestiging=JA"><input type="text" id="kamer" name="kamer"><br>
Weet je zeker dat je gevolgt wilt worden?
<br>
<input type="submit"id="Submit"name="Submit" value="Ja">
</form>';
echo '
<a href="index.php?p=tools_volg_kamer" target="_self">Nee</a> | <a href="index.php?p=tools_volg_kamer_'. $aanofuit .'" target="_self">Volgen '. $aanofuit .'</a>';
}
```

And that gives me an empty result in the database. So how can I fix this in a proper way that it makes a form that sends the "kamerurl" to tools_volg_kamer&bevestiging=ja and sets it in the database?

Comment: you need to take a look at code injection, because that way hackers can take over your website/database. I took a look at your profile and shaw that has been pointed out to you before. Furthermore, I have noticed that you almost never accept a answer could you look into that?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's the difference between `UPDATE` and `INSERT`.

`UPDATE` only edits the row while `INSERT` (*which I think you want*) adds new row on the table.

```
INSERT INTO volg_dj_aan_uit (aan_of_uit,kamerurl) 
VALUES ('aanzetten','$kamerurl')
```

the `UPDATE` syntax

```
UPDATE volg_dj_aan_uit 
SET    aan_of_uit = 'aanzetten',
       kamerurl   = '$kamerurl';
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using PreparedStatements you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)